# The first character in the input file is the last character in the output file and vice-versa

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, swap

I want to print out the first character in the input file is the last character in the output file and vice-versa. But I stuck at how to print out the output.

I need to use arrays. I will read from input file into a character array and the write from the array to the output file.

Example:

> Input.txt: A B C D E H
>
> output.txt: H B C D E A

```
This is my code 

    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string FileName, FileName2;
        string s, temp, FirstChar, LastChar;;
        char again = 'Y';
        bool close = false;
        char MAXSIZE[1024];
        while (close == false)
        {
            cout << "Open the file: ";
            cin >> FileName;
            ifstream ReadFromFile(FileName);
            if (ReadFromFile.is_open())
            {
                cout << "Succeed to open the file!\n";

                // Read character from the input to array
                while (!ReadFromFile.eof())
                {
                    ReadFromFile >> MAXSIZE;
                    cout << MAXSIZE << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;

                cout << "Enter the first character: ";
                cin >> FirstChar;
                cout << "Enter the last character: ";
                cin >> LastChar;
                swap(FirstChar, LastChar);

     // I stuck at here

                ifstream in(FileName);
                cout << "Enter a name for a copy file: ";
                cin >> FileName2;
                ofstream out(FileName2);
                while (getline(in, s))
                        out << s << "\n";


                cout << "Close the program and then open your copy file.";
                cout << endl << endl;
                close = true;
            }
            else{
                cout << "Failed to open the file!\n";
                do {

                    cout << "Do you want to do it again(Y) or Close (N)? ";
                    cin >> again;
                } while (again != 'y' && again != 'Y' && again != 'n' && again != 'N');

                if (again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
                    close = false;
                else
                    close = true;

                cout << endl;
            }
        }

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: if the file is not big, real all, reverse, and write back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your task (according to your explanation) require:

1) reading from input file to array

2) changing the first and the last characters

3) saving array to output file

So, the first and the last characters should not be asked from standard input (keyboard).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

// filenames can be given as command line arguments
// change the code if you want to read them from standard input
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream inf;
    ofstream outf;
    size_t counter = 0;
    const size_t MAXSIZE = 1024; // MAXSIZE - name of constant
    char buffer[MAXSIZE];        // buffer - name of array
    // check the command line arguments
    // Alternatively you can define: string InpFileName, OutFileName; 
    // as it is in your code and enter values (cin >>) instead using argv
    // if so, you should change inf.open(argv[1]); to inf.open(InpFileName);
    // and outf.open(argv[2]); to outf.open(OutFileName);
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        cerr << "Two arguments are required:" << endl
            << " 1) name of existing file (to read)" << endl
            << " 2) name of new file (to create)" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    // open files
    inf.open(argv[1]);
    outf.open(argv[2]);
    // check files
    if (!inf.is_open() || !outf.is_open())
    {
        cout << "ERROR: some trouble with files." << endl;
        return 2; // stop the program
    }
    // process
    // 1) reading
    while (counter < MAXSIZE){
        buffer[counter] = inf.get();
        if (buffer[counter] != EOF)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else
        {
            counter--; // the last character is not valid
            break; // end of file
        }
    }
    // 2) changing
    char b = buffer[counter];
    buffer[counter] = buffer[0];
    buffer[0] = b;
    // 3) output
    for (int i = 0; i <= counter; i++)
    {
        outf.put(buffer[i]);
    }
    // close files
    inf.close();
    outf.close();
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Clarify the task for cases when some unprintable character (like space) is the first or the last

Comment: I stuck at the 3rd step

Comment: Can you make it easier because I just a newbie of programming

Comment: I have added some comments and changed code to make it easier

Comment: Thank you so much, even some of the code I haven't learned yet. I just learn some basic C++.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a homework problem for a C++ class.  One hint which may help is to
divide the file into blocks of X bytes and read the blocks in reverse order....

std::istream::seekg